# Uncaught ReferenceError: bunny_data is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

the js code is like:

```js
    var images = new Parse.Query("Images");
 var bunny_data = [];

 images.equalTo("indexImg","T");
 images.find({
        success: function(objects) {
            /*for(var i = 0;i<objects.length;i++){
             var object =  objects[i];
             imgs.push(object.get('imgUrl'));
            };
            bunny_view = $("#bunny-template").html();
            alert(imgs);
   $('#container').append(_.template(bunny_view, imgs));*/
   for(var i = 0;i<objects.length;i++){
             var object =  objects[i];
             bunny_data.push(object.get('imgUrl'));
            };

   bunny_view = $("#bunny-template").html();
   alert(bunny_data);
   $('#container').append(_.template(bunny_view, bunny_data));
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("An error occured :(");
        }
 });
```

the html is like

```html
<script type='text/template' id="bunny-template">
  <div> 
     <h5><%= name %></h5>
     <ul>
       <% for(var tag in bunny_data) { %>
           <li><%= bunny_data[tag] %></li>
       <% } %>
     </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

when i run this code, the err is Uncaught ReferenceError: bunny_data is not defined.
but i still get alert popup with correct data.
ty very much！

Comment: Seems like you forgot to declare var bunny_data = [];

Comment: where you declare variable `bunny_data` ??

Comment: at the line two i declare var bunny_data

Comment: Please specify the line number where error  is given and modify the question with that line

Comment: i can use bunny_data in the alert(bunny_data); and the data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a variable that's local in one scope and global in another, which is why you can `alert` with the correct data in your image finding function but in the other scope, your html, `bunny_data` will not be defined.